# iOS[Swift] : Parse Facebook Login "Use of unresolved identifier 'permissions'"

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform, ios8

I"m building an iOS app in swift that has facebook login via parse SDK.

I have gone through the Facebook SDK tutorial for iOS and Parse

Somehow it's throwing this error "Use of unresolved identifier 'permissions'" at `PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions`

[Parse Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers-signup/iOS)

Here's the code

```
@IBAction func facebookLogin() {
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, block: {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    })
}
```

Here's the bridging header file

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, block: {
                                     ^
```

You are passing a parameter 'permissions' which isn't declared anywhere. This is what the error is referring to.

If you don't want to request and additional permissions you can pass in an empty array as follows:

```
@IBAction func facebookLogin() {
    let permissions = [] // << declaring permissions as empty array
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, block: {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        // ... 
    })
}
```